# What's the point of automated integration test here?

Tags: integration-testing

Yes, I did read the 'Related Questions' in the box above after I typed this =). They still didn't help me as much as I'd like, as I understand what the difference between the two are - I'm just not sure if I need it in my specific case.

So I have a fully unit tested (simple & small) application. I have some 'Job' class with a single public Run() method + ctors which takes in an Excel spreadsheet as parameter, extracts the data, checks the database to see if we already have that data, and if not, makes a request to a third party vendor, takes that response, puts it in the database and then completes the job (db update again)

I have IConnection to talk to vendor, IParser to parse excel/vendor files, IDataAccess to do all database access. My Job class is lean & mean and doesnt do much logic, even though in reality it is doing *all* of the logic, it's really just 'chaining along' data through to the composite objects...

So all the composite objects are unit tested themselves, including the DAL, and even my Run() method on the Job class is unit tested fully using mocks for all possible code paths..

So - do I need to do any type of integration test at this point, other then run the app to see if it works? Is my test(s) of the Run() method with mocks considered my integration test(s)? Or should my integration test use real instances instead of mocks, and then  Assert database values at the end, based on known excel spreadsheet input? But that's what all my unit tests are doing already (just in seperate places, and the mocked Run test makes sure those places 'connect')! Following the DRY methodology, I just don't see a need to do an integration test here...

Am I missing something obvious guys? Many thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest thing you're missing is the actual behaviour of your external systems. While your unit tests may certainly assert that the individual steps perform the expected action, they do little to reveal the run-time issues that may arise when accessing external systems. Your external systems may also contain data you do not know about.

So yes, I think you need both. You do not necessarily need to be equally detailed in both tests. Sometimes you can just let the integration test be a smoke test

Comment: thanks for the advice. By 'smoke test' you basically mean run the app and make sure no exceptions are thrown?

Comment: Yes, or very superficial tests